# Change size of object when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a hover effect to my object using CSS, but it seems like the html is too complex for it to change. Therefor I ask you for some advice.

The :hover effect is going to change the size and color of the object.

I have tagged jquery and javascript incase it's easier to do the effect in that language.

**PHP**

```
<div class="holder forsideikonholder">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="prosess">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="col-md-4 foto">
                        <li>
                            <object data="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-foto.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-foto.png">
                            </object>
                            <p class="thin">Fotografering</p>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#">
                    <div class="col-md-4 video">
                        <li>
                            <object data="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-video.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-video.png">
                            </object>
                            <p class="thin">Videoproduksjon</p>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#">
                    <div class="col-md-4 web">
                        <li>
                            <object data="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-web.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikon-web.png">
                            </object>
                            <p class="thin">Webutvikling</p>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Here is the most important CSS for this question:

```
.forsideikonholder .prosess {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.forsideikonholder object {
    width: 50%; 
}
```

I have tried to do it like this, but as I mentioned, - it seems like it's to complex and I am not selecting the right object.

```
.forsideikonholder a:hover {
        width: 60%; 
    }

  .forsideikonholder object:hover {
        width: 60%; 
    }
```

Here is the site: http://goo.gl/kbWlGR

Scroll down till you see the orange part with 3 icons.

Comment: a tags are inline, so css width has no effect on them

Comment: Thank you. So how would you recommend doing this?

Comment: Firstly, your HTML markup isn't valid, an anchor tag cannot be direct child of UL element, only LI or TEMPLATE can be

Comment: Thank you. It's not going to be anchor tags, but <a> tags linking to different sites. But anyways: I am going to move them to li element, if thats what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `a` tag is an inline element and its size can't be modified by default. You have here to transform your `a` tags into blocks with `display: block;`. That way you will be able to play with their size (without changing anything in your `:hover` rule).

Moreover, your markup is wrong: a `ul` mustn't contain anything else than `li` tags: move your `li` tags to make them encapsulate the whole content of your buttons.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good explaining. Solved the problem with the size, but do you have a working solution on how to change the color of the objects this way?

Comment: How to change the color depends on what the objects are. Here I see that the text in your `a` tags is just, well, text, so using the `color` property should be enough.
About your SVG icons, it will be more tricky. It's been a long time since I played with SVG but, as these icons aren't directly in the DOM tree, the only solution I see here is using JavaScript (maybe there is a better way, with just CSS) to modify the style of your icons when the parent (the `a` tag) is hovering.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was just like I thought. Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.forsideikonholder a {
       display:block;
    }
```